# Fail to import bootstrap-sass files

Tags: sass, bootstrap-sass

I installed bootstrap-sass by npm.
$ npm install bootstrap-sass
Then, put the import on my sass file.
@import 'bootstrap';
When I run the compile task this import fails. I have the bootstrap-sass folder in the node-modules one. Should I use a relative path to it? or copy the bootstrap folder from node-modules to my sass folder?.

Answer (score 0):

When you use npm to install bootstrap, the bootstrap installs in "./node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" folder. So make sure you install the bootstrap in the right directory!

Comment: Yes, But I need the bootstrap sass files to compile with my own sass files. I don't know how to import the bootstrap files, If I have to link them from node_modules/bootstrap folder or copy the files to my own sass folder.